# Which Transcend Jetdrive Lite fits into MB Pro 13" early 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, sd-card

I want to expand my MB Pro diskspace by a seamless SD-card. There are different Jetdrive Lite versions, but they're specified for the MB Pro 13" back to late 2012 only.

Any experiences with MB Pro 13" early 2011?

Comment: I think jetdrive lite 330 for late 2012 maybe fits in your laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bought a **JetDrive Lite 130** and it fits seamlessly into the **MB Pro 13" early 2011** card slot and is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

http://in.transcend-info.com/Apple/jetdrivelite/

The answers are given in the table at the bottom of the link...

Comment: The answer isn't given, as MB Pro early 2011 is NOT listed in the table.